# Ubuntu 20.04 newly installed; No ethernet connection

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I'm aware of the number of similar questions in this site, but most that I saw have solution's that require special permissions, which in my case are not available to me.

I've just insalled Ubuntu 20.04 in a Dualboot. After plugging the Ethernet cable, I get a "Connected - 100 Mb/s" but a question mark appears on the network symbol. I cannot use Mozilla Firefox to open any site. It doesn't explicitly says "No connection", but it keeps loading forever. I tried desabling Ipv6 as some suggested in this site but it didn't work. A very similar problem to mine (I am unfortunately not able to link the question since I'm writing from my phone) suggested creating the file 10-globally-managed-devices.conf which should be located at /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d (the file doesn't exist for me). I however do not have the write/execute permissions on this folder nor I am able to put myself as owner.
Any ideas would be gratly appreciated.

I'm available to provide any information/command outputs that are necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Create the file with sudo in terminal.

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

Comment: I explictly mentioned this solution in my question, unfortunately I don't have the permissions to create the file.

Comment: There is no need to downvote my valid answer. The only way to create the file in this location is by using sudo. Your normal user does not have permission in this directory, hence the use of sudo. What error comes up by trying my solution compared to the touch command without the sudo prefix?

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted.

Comment: With sudo, I am able to create the file. However this does not seem to solve the problem; I created the file and ran service network-manager restart, to no avail.